# FSK generation with Timer 555

Tags: frequency, modulation

On the Internet I found FSK generator connection diagram. And I'm trying to connect up it in Qucs.
I' sure, 555 timer is working properly. But at the output of the whole schema I get unclear result.

P.S. Output.Vt does not depend on the input bit stream.

Look, please, what could be wrong?
[image: Qucs schema]

[image: Internet schema]

[image: Output]

Comment: This is a non-coherent FSK, the duty cycle varies between the two frequencies, the output is square and not sinusoidal, among some other things crossing my mind. What's this to be used for? (You need to allow more time for your .TRAN period for the output.)

Comment: @jonk Thank you! The final diagrams are [Diagrams](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559433554/036fea16/26741641.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the left side of the original circuit you will see that the input data rate is expected to be 150 Hz, and the output frequency then switches between 1070 Hz and 1270 Hz.

Your input signal is 100 MHz, much too fast for this circuit. To perform FSK with an input frequency of 100 MHz you will need an oscillator with a nominal frequency of 1 GHz or so...and a 555 timer will never achieve that.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the parameters. I hope that's all right now. But the output was not sinusoid. What could be the reason?      [Schema](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559419954/0f2def21/26740551.png).  [Diagrams](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559419995/d079866e/26740553.png).

Comment: @alexhak You might want to allow more time in the plot. You are only allowing 100 ns in the chart I see right now.

Comment: The input signal needs to swing between **logic** 1 and 0...that's 5V and 0V....not 1V and 0V.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thank you! Your advice helped me (with 5V). [Diagrams](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559433554/036fea16/26741641.png)