# FSK demodulation with LM565

Tags: frequency, demodulation

On the Internet I found FSK demodulation connection diagram with LM565 . And I'm trying to connect up it in Qucs. At the output of the whole schema I get unclear result.

In my previous topic we were able to come to the right decision with FSK generation [Topic1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441501/fsk-generation-with-timer-555). So FSK generator works properly.

I suspect the error is in the circuit of LM565. In many articles there are different versions of internal circuit diagram of IC PLL LM565.
I did as [here](https://futurlec.com/Datasheet/Linear/LM565N.pdf).
But I don't understand the element that is marked in red.

Look, please, what could be wrong?

[image: Internet schema]

[image: Internet schema 2]

[image: My schema 1]

[image: My schema 2]

[image: My schema 3]

Comment: That transistor symbol indicates a special on-silicon layout approach. Get a die photo and zoom in, then we can answer your question. Or perhaps find an app-note written by Signetics (the IC design company).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I made a diagram using datasheet by National Semiconductor ([Click here](https://futurlec.com/Datasheet/Linear/LM565N.pdf)) on page 4. Or zoomed photo [Click here](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559491798/ec9adcd1/26747990.png)

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Any idea what that element is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your VCO range is a couple orders of magnitude , your signal shifts maybe 25% and your LPF should reject mixer output (2f) fundamental by > 20dB this below signal excursion and is too close to 0Vdc meaning not centred.

Other than that it’s ok.

Comment: At the output of the circuit (Output2.Vt) there  is a straight line. But I have to get a broken line (one - for logic "0", and another - for logic "1").

Comment: The frequency to Vdc conversion after filter must be noise free and yet shift more than Op Amp input offset.  Allow 10 carrier cycle delay for detection may be expected due to LPF time constant to reject carrier.

Comment: I added LPF and "aligned straight". I expected to get Out5.Vt as Input.Vt. I don't quite understand how to achieve this. Please, [Look this](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559502338/bd6d12ec/26749697.png) and [Look this](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1559502419/32a6af97/26749730.png)

Comment: Understand the conditions for the comparator to work and any differences between your cct and the example given.